# Update error: E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20220809.1) jammy Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: updates, repository

```
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20220809.1) jammy InRelease
Err:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20220809.1) jammy Release
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Hit:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                       
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                                     
Hit:5 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                
Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                    
Hit:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                      
Hit:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20220809.1) jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

In addition, I am unable to open *Software and Updates* on my laptop to change the settings.

Comment: `man sources.list` might help you learn about the source (erm sorry) of the issue

Answer (score 4):

Disable the cdrom repository:

```
sudo sed -e '/cdrom/s/^/#/' -i /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
```